# How do I insert into a form with over 100 fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, insert-into

I've created a user form in which once the submit button is pressed I would like to send/insert the data to mysql database adding a new record. The form has over 100 input fields. How can I accomplish this. Here is my sample php code.

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


//Variables for connecting to your database.
            //These variable values come from your hosting account.
            $hostname = "hostname";
            $username = "username";
            $password = "password";
            $dbname = "dbname";
            $mystuff = "tenant_lname","tenant_fname","tenant_mname","ssn","dl_number","dl_state","birthday","tenant_hphone","tenant_wphone","tenant_cphone","curr_street","curr__unit","curr_city","curr_state","curr_zip","how_long_from","how_long_to","last_rent_mnt","last_rent_amt","own_man_name","own_man_tel","curr_reason","pre_street","pre_unit","pre_city","pre_state","pre_zip","pre_from","pre_to","pre_last_rent","pre_amt","pre_owner","pre_owner_tel","pre_reason","sec_pre_street","sec_pre_unit","sec_pre_city","sec_pre_state","sec_pre_zip","sec_pre_from","sec_pre_to","sec_pre_last_paid_mnt","sec_pre_amt","sec_pre_owner","sec_pre_owner_tel","sec_pre_reason","curr_emp_name","curr_emp_add","curr_emp_phone","curr_emp_pos","curr_emp_bus_type","curr_emp_sup","curr_emp_from","curr_emp_to","curr_emp_salary","pre_emp_name","pre_emp_add","pre_emp_phone","pre_emp_pos","pre_emp_bus_type","pre_emp_sup_name","pre_emp_from","pre_emp_to","pre_emp_salary","move_date","addntl_occ_name","addntl_occ_age","addntl_occ_relation","addntl_ft","addntl_pt","addntl_occ1_name","addntl_occ1_age","addntl_occ1_relation","addntl_occ1_ft","addntl_occ1_pt","addntl_occ2_name","addntl_occ2_age","addnt2_occ1_relation","addntl_occ2_ft","addntl_occ2_pt","addntl_occ3_name","addntl_occ3_age","addntl_occ3_relation","addntl_occ3_ft","addntl_occ3_pt","credit_yes","credit_no","det_yes","det_no","evict_yes","evict_no","bnkry_yes","bnkry_no","fel_yes","fel_no","pet_yes","pet_no","pet_numb","pet_type","furn_yes","furn_no","ins_cov_yes","ins_cov_no","ints_yes","ints_no","ints_type","smoke_yes","smoke_no","occ_smoke_yes","occ_smoke_no","explain_smoke","bnk_name","bnk_add","checking","checking_bal","saving","saving_bal","bnk_name1","bnk_add1","checking1","checking_bal1","saving1","saving_bal1","other_income","credit_name","credit_add","credit_city","credit_acct","credit_bal","credit_payment","credit_name1","credit_add1","credit_city1","credit_acct1","credit_bal1","credit_payment1","credit_acct2_name","credit_add2","credit_city2","credit_acc2","credit_bal2","credit_payment2","credit_acc3_name","credit_acc3_add","credit_acc3_city","credit_acc3_number","credit_acc3_bal","credit_acc3_payment","emer_contact_name","emer_contact_add","emer_relation","emer_phone","reg_owner_yes","reg_owner_no","reg_who","vehicle_year","vehicle_make","vehicle_model","vehicle_color","vehicle_license","veh_state","vehicle2_year","vehicle2_make","vehicle2_model","vehicle2_color","vehicle2_license","veh2_state";



$con = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password");
if (!$con){
die ("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());   
}

mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO dbname ($mystuff) VALUES ('$_POST[$mystuff]')";

mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to do this without typing in all of the field names

Comment: 1. refrain from using mysql extension in php as it has been deprecated 2. use pdo  for parameterized queries

Comment: @Don Austin: You are basically looking for something called an array: http://php.net/array and then something called [loops](http://php.net/control-structures.foreach) - the rest like the HTML form and the SQL query you seem to already know but take care that the database client library you use makes it easy to write unsafe code and is not under active development any longer.

Comment: For safety's sake, you do need to type in all the field names. You will not be able to write [robust SQL code](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesw/archive/2011/10/03/a-list-of-sql-best-practices.aspx) otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

$mystuff should be an array.

You can generate your query and form with an loop.

Do validation if these is for productive use!

$_POST is also an array, so  $_POST["field1", "field2", ...] ist an syntax error. 
You can only access one key at once e.g. $_POST['field1'] . ',' . $_POST['field2']

You can join all values in an array by an char (e.g. ',') with [implode()](http://php.net/implode)

rethink your Database schema!

untested:

```
    <html>
`enter code here`<head>
`enter code here`</head>
<body>
<?php
>if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Variables for connecting to your database.
    //These variable values come from your hosting account.
    $hostname = "hostname";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";
    $mystuff = array(  "tenant_lname","tenant_fname","tenant_mname","ssn","dl_number","dl_state","birthday","tenant_hphone","tenant_wphone","tenant_cphone","curr_street","curr__unit","curr_city","curr_state","curr_zip","how_long_from","how_long_to","last_rent_mnt","last_rent_amt","own_man_name","own_man_tel","curr_reason","pre_street","pre_unit","pre_city","pre_state","pre_zip","pre_from","pre_to","pre_last_rent","pre_amt","pre_owner","pre_owner_tel","pre_reason","sec_pre_street","sec_pre_unit","sec_pre_city","sec_pre_state","sec_pre_zip","sec_pre_from","sec_pre_to","sec_pre_last_paid_mnt","sec_pre_amt","sec_pre_owner","sec_pre_owner_tel","sec_pre_reason","curr_emp_name","curr_emp_add","curr_emp_phone","curr_emp_pos","curr_emp_bus_type","curr_emp_sup","curr_emp_from","curr_emp_to","curr_emp_salary","pre_emp_name","pre_emp_add","pre_emp_phone","pre_emp_pos","pre_emp_bus_type","pre_emp_sup_name","pre_emp_from","pre_emp_to","pre_emp_salary","move_date","addntl_occ_name","addntl_occ_age","addntl_occ_relation","addntl_ft","addntl_pt","addntl_occ1_name","addntl_occ1_age","addntl_occ1_relation","addntl_occ1_ft","addntl_occ1_pt","addntl_occ2_name","addntl_occ2_age","addnt2_occ1_relation","addntl_occ2_ft","addntl_occ2_pt","addntl_occ3_name","addntl_occ3_age","addntl_occ3_relation","addntl_occ3_ft","addntl_occ3_pt","credit_yes","credit_no","det_yes","det_no","evict_yes","evict_no","bnkry_yes","bnkry_no","fel_yes","fel_no","pet_yes","pet_no","pet_numb","pet_type","furn_yes","furn_no","ins_cov_yes","ins_cov_no","ints_yes","ints_no","ints_type","smoke_yes","smoke_no","occ_smoke_yes","occ_smoke_no","explain_smoke","bnk_name","bnk_add","checking","checking_bal","saving","saving_bal","bnk_name1","bnk_add1","checking1","checking_bal1","saving1","saving_bal1","other_income","credit_name","credit_add","credit_city","credit_acct","credit_bal","credit_payment","credit_name1","credit_add1","credit_city1","credit_acct1","credit_bal1","credit_payment1","credit_acct2_name","credit_add2","credit_city2","credit_acc2","credit_bal2","credit_payment2","credit_acc3_name","credit_acc3_add","credit_acc3_city","credit_acc3_number","credit_acc3_bal","credit_acc3_payment","emer_contact_name","emer_contact_add","emer_relation","emer_phone","reg_owner_yes","reg_owner_no","reg_who","vehicle_year","vehicle_make","vehicle_model","vehicle_color","vehicle_license","veh_state","vehicle2_year","vehicle2_make","vehicle2_model","vehicle2_color","vehicle2_license","veh2_state");


    $sql_values=array();
    foreach($mystuff as $fieldname) {
        /* do validation! */

        $sql_values[$fieldname] = "'" . mysql_real_excape_stiring($_POST[$fieldname]) . "'";
    }


    $con = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password");
    if (!$con){
        die ("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbname (".implode(',', $mystuff).") VALUES (" . implode(',', $sql_values) . ")";

    mysql_query($sql,$con);

    mysql_close($con);
}


foreach($mystuff as $fieldname) {
    echo "...an input field...";
}

?>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create inputs something like :

```
<input type="text" name="datas[firstname]"/>
<input type="text" name="datas[lastname]"/>
```

You can process the data using :

```
<?php

$datas = $_POST['datas'];
$columns = implode(",",array_keys($datas));

//add ' since mysql use ' for strings
$values = implode("','",$datas);

$sql = "INSERT INTO dbname (".$columns.") VALUES ('".$values."')";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `$_POST` is already an array, why not just use `foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)`?

Comment: Iterating the array is an alternative solution because we should build the column by concating $k as you defined above. Yes, you're right, $_POST['datas'] is already an array, so instead of iterating it, I'd prefer using implode which requires array to be the parameter too.

Comment: And here it comes the SQL Injection Company.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that those codes are susceptible of being injected. I do recommend to use any libraries/frameworks but what I answered was the basic only.

Comment: At this point I don't believe that I can change my input names which are associated with my ccs. I'm new at all of this and now you've got me wondering how to do this using PDO to help prevent the SQL Injection I keep reading about. Is there another way to do this without changing the input names? Thank you in advance. @UsmanTiono

Comment: you've got me wondering how to do this using PDO to help prevent the SQL Injection I keep reading about. Is there another way to do this without changing the input names? Thank you in advance.@Kolink

Comment: Sorry for a late response. CSS depends on the element classes or id, not the name, so you can change the input name and let the class or id the same as previous. Here is a link how to prevent SQL Injection : [How To Prevent SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)